# How to avoid integer overflow?

Tags: c++, variables, integer-overflow

In the following C++ code, 32767 + 1 = -32768.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
short var = 32767;
var++;
std::cout << var;
std::cin.get();
}
```

Is there any way to just leave "var" as 32767, without errors?

Comment: Do you get whats going on here?  You've hit the ceiling for an integer (short), so adding one more flips the signs to the maximum negative amount for an integer.

Comment: If you want a different mode where integers don't automatically wrap around, it doesn't exist, sorry.

Comment: This reminds me of why I [can't sleep](http://xkcd.com/571/). :-)

Comment: This is called [saturation arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic). It can be highly illogical, so be warned. What's 32767+1-1?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
if (var < 32767) var++;
```

By the way, you shouldn't hardcode the constant, use `numeric_limits<short>::max()` defined in `<limits>` header file instead.

You can encapsulate this functionality in a function template:

```
template <class T>
void increment_without_wraparound(T& value) {
   if (value < numeric_limits<T>::max())
     value++;
}
```

and use it like:

```
short var = 32767;
increment_without_wraparound(var); // pick a shorter name!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(){ 
unsigned short var = 32767; 
var++; 
std::cout << var; 
std::cin.get(); 
}
```

Comment: This answers the question that was asked, but not, I suspect, the question that was intended.

Answer (score -1):

use 'unsigned short int' or 'long int'

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
long int var = 32767;
var++;
std::cout << var;
std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Then x = 32676; x++ will result in x == 32677, not 32676.

Comment: OK, so how do you avoid the overflow on an unsigned 64 bit integer?